# Navigation too long, any real case solves this issue?

Tags: navigation, sliders, long

I'm working in a project where navigation is too long (because the app is rich function and owner doesn't want user to click too much). The issue is there's some items hidden at bottom, my solution is create UI effect (gradient slide), so user knows there's still sth under and they should scroll down.

I don't think this is the best solution, do you guys have any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding gradient may not suggest that there are some hidden items at the bottom in some cases.You can improve it by

1. Always showing half content of the last item indicating that there are some more contents in the screen.

### [image]

2. you can enable a scroll bar once user starts interacting with the navigation panel,

Comment: I agree with your first point. But about the second one, touch devices don't usually have scrollbars; if taking second solution why only display the scrollbar when the user starts scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to the problem is in fact to simplify the menu structure in the first place. If you really do require so many menu items then it's probably better to split them using sub-menus.

Here is an article that explains why it's one of the common mistakes in navigation.
[Common website navigation mistakes](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/common-website-navigation-mistakes/)
Look for #4

About a possible UI solution to your request:
Here is an example of sub-menus.

[image]

Source: [Mobile menu ui inspiration](https://medium.muz.li/mobile-menu-ui-inspiration-d94de7173341)